# C# DevExpress - ProgressBar fills immediately on _DoWork

Tags: c#, devexpress

Just as the title says. First time using this control so I'm not sure what's up.

my OnLoad

```
bw = new BackgroundWorker();

bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
bw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bw_ProgressChanged);
bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
```

Inside my button click event

```
// Set props for progress bar
progressBarControl1.EditValue = 1;
progressBarControl1.Properties.Minimum = 0;
// cboTables names is a checkedListBox
progressBarControl1.Properties.Maximum = cboTableNames.CheckedItems.Count;
progressBarControl1.Properties.Step = 1;

// Start BW worker
bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

DoWork

```
protected void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   int counter = 0;
    if (cboTableNames.CheckedItems.Count != 0)
        {
            // Get selected items
            foreach (string item in cboTableNames.CheckedItems)
            {
                // Pass off for archiving
                _myIO.Archive(item, _sqlConn, bw); // I pass bw 
            }
        }
        else
        {
           // Catch if the user tries to submit without table name selection(s)
            MessageBox.Show("You must select a table name to archive.");
        }
    }
```

Now the goal is to not fill the progress bar as I cycle through each item that's been checked. But in my IO file, I am submitting items to a database. The goal is to reflect progress of each SQL transaction being inserted.

```
// Encapsulated within a loop that is iterating through records and inserting values 
//into the DB. #magic

// For progressbar
pgCounter++;
bw.ReportProgress(pgCounter);
```

Now the odd thing right out of the gate, is the moment `bw.RunWorkerAsync()` redirects me to the DoWork function. The moment that occurs my progress bar fills 100%. What am I missing here?

Also, I haven't seen too many folks invoking `.ReportProgress` from other classes other than where BackgroundWorker is usually defined. Any tips on the correct way of using that would also be appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: This is not the best option but I usually just use `thread.sleep` and add half a second, usually processes are too fast for the progress bar to visually work the way we want to, but I repeat this is not the best course of action.

Comment: @edrodriguez - A variant on the [speed up loop](http://thedailywtf.com/articles/The-Speedup-Loop)? :-)

Comment: hey thanks for the input. tried adding thread.sleep as you suggested, but it was to no avail.